# import error in Python PDFtables

Tags: python-2.7

I got  an import error when tyring to use [PDFtables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdftables). I'm using python 2.7.

```
 from  pdftables.pdf_document import *
```

here is the error I get:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdftables/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from pdftables import *

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdftables/pdftables.py in <module>()
     22 import codecs
     23 
---> 24 from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
     25 from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
     26 from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice

ImportError: cannot import name PDFDocument
```

Yet when I try,

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import *
```

everything goes fine.

**Update 1**

I'm trying to reproduce the example from the documentation of [PDFtables](https://pdftables.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
Yet it is the PDFtables 0.0.3 and I'm using PDFtable 0.0.4. I could not get my cursor on the latest documentation. May be the best way is to use the PDFtables 0.03 ?

**Update 2**

I uninstalled PDFtables 0.04 for the PDFtables 0.03 and it turns out that PDFtables 0.03 produces the same error.

** Update 3 **

Based on the lead below I came the of conclusion that the issue might come from pdf miner.
from the [doc](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/), it seems that

PDFDocument class is moved to pdfdocument.py.

can anyone confirm ?

any idea around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is not strange that

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import *
```

It loads classes related to pdfminer.pdfparser.  On the other hand

```
from  pdftables.pdf_document import *
```

loads all classes/code related to pdftables.pdf_document. Why it doesn't work can have multiple reasons. The most probable reason is that "pdf_document" does not exist (maybe a typo?)

Answer to updated question:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import *
```

Works because it just loads all submodules under pdfminer.pdfparser it can find. The top import has absolute imports, namely:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
```

It requires PDFParser and PDFDocument (which is missing) to be present in the pdfminer.pdfparser module

Comment: I would suggest, checking if you get the same error with the version equivalent to the documentation (0.0.3)

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Just did `pip install pdftables`